# 'SubQuery Returns More Than One Row' Using Case When

Tags: mysql, case

I appear to be having a great deal of difficulty in giving a discount to the user when they have two adults and a child making a booking...the output text is saying as shown in the title. While I am aware of the issue I am not sure how I can fix it to make the result more unique.

For reference the prices are coming from a different table but everything else resides in the booking.

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance

```
UPDATE BOOKING SET TotalCost=
(SELECT SUM(

CASE WHEN NumAdults = 2 AND NumChilds = 1 THEN
(NumAdults*(SELECT Cost FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Adult'))
+
(NumChilds*(SELECT Cost FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Child' / 2))


ELSE
(NumAdults*(SELECT Cost FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Adult'))
+
(NumChilds*(SELECT Cost FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Child'))
END
))
WHERE BookID  = 1
```

Comment: Consider providing CREATE and INSERT statements, and a desired result

Comment: Is there only one row on cost for agetype of Adult and one row on cost for agetype of child?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic fix is to do the SUM within the sub queries:-

```
UPDATE BOOKING SET TotalCost=
(
    CASE 
        WHEN NumAdults = 2 AND NumChilds = 1 
        THEN
            (NumAdults * (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Adult'))
            +
            (NumChilds * (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Child' / 2))

        ELSE
            (NumAdults * (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Adult'))
            +
            (NumChilds * (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Child'))
    END
)
WHERE BookID  = 1
```

But not convinced there isn't a better way to do the whole query if we could see the table descriptions and some sample data

For example if the price is unique for each of adult and child then it could be done like this:-

```
UPDATE BOOKING a
LEFT OUTER JOIN prices pa ON pa.AgeType = 'Adult'
LEFT OUTER JOIN prices pc ON pc.AgeType = 'Child'
SET TotalCost = CASE 
                    WHEN NumAdults = 2 AND NumChilds = 1 
                    THEN NumAdults * pa.Cost + (NumChilds * pc.Cost / 2)
                    ELSE NumAdults * pa.Cost + NumChilds * pc.Cost
                END
WHERE BookID  = 1
```

Comment: This one works, Quite an amateur mistake on my part so thanks for the help...marked as solved...Also thanks to the other dude Subin for a quick answer

Answer (score 1):

All occurance of this     (`NumAdults*(SELECT Cost FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Adult')`

should be `(NumAdults*(SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM prices WHERE AgeType = 'Adult')`

There you were multiplying `Numadults` with `resultset`.

Hope this helps